# How to retrieve data frame columns by evaluating formula components?

Tags: r, r-caret

I have a formula:

```
form <- outcome ~ var1 + var2 + (!is.na(var3) | var3 == "ANY") + (var1:var2)
```

Let's say the formula has 4 components:

- var1
- var2
- (!is.na(var3) | var3 == "ANY")
- (var1:var2)

I would like to obtain a column for each formula component.

In the case of var1 and var2 it would be easy:

```
dataset$var1
dataset$var2
```

I know is possible to use `eval(parse(text="(!is.na(var3) | var3 == "ANY")"))` with a combination of the `with` function. But it won't work with some formula expressions (like `(var1:var2)`).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `?terms`.  In particular, the `variables` attribute of a terms object is an unevaluated list

```
attr(terms(form), 'variables')
#list(outcome, var1, var2, !is.na(var3) | var3 == "ANY")
```

which can be evaluated with `eval`.  Depending on the syntax you want to support in your formula, you may need to write your own `terms` method.  The `terms.formula` method is the one used by `lm` and others.